# How to create a unmanaged Package from a production which has Person Account Activated?

Tags: managed-package, person-accounts, production

I want to create a Package for all Objects from Production which has been activated with Person Account. when I try to create package(Unmanaged) with all Object it throws a Error like this
 [image]

If you can't read it from image ERROR IS " Salesforce.com does not currently allow export of components referencing person account fields "

what is the solution for this issue ? Is there any workaround ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Winter 15' Release we can able to Create managed and unmanaged Package which has Person Account Activated
[Release Notes](http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/winter15/release-notes/rn_forcecom_development_additional.htm)