# How to move data from 'Full copy sandbox' to 'Developer sandbox'?

Tags: force.com, sandbox

I have activated a 'Full copy sandbox' and created around 15 custom object . In each object I have 20+ custom fields to 65+ custom fields.

Now If I create a 'Developer sandbox' how to get all custom object and fields in 'Developer sandbox', will it be there already by default ? I mean If I activate a 'Developer sandbox' all custom object and fields will be there from 'Full copy sandbox' ?

Answer (score 1):

Sandboxes take their source metadata from the production org only therefore making a new sandbox cannot derive metadata from another sandbox.

You have a few options to move your objects and fields, which include change sets (assuming the sandboxes are from the same production org), creating an unmanaged package from your full sandbox, or deploying objects using the Force.com IDE or similar metadata deployment tool (Force.com Migration Tool, MavensMate, BrainEngine, etc.)

Comment: Using change set can i deploy from "F C Sandbox" to "Dev Sandbox" ?

Comment: As long as they are connected to the same production org, yes.

Comment: using 'unmanaged package' will it come even if Person account is activated, I had asked similar question some days back [link](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/25258/how-to-create-a-unmanaged-package-from-a-production-which-has-person-account-act)

Comment: There are issues with person accounts and packaging which I don't fully understand. You may have issues there.